# Subclassed UIView not displaying UIImageViews added to it

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview, addsubview

So I have class called CSImageViews (subclass of uiview), that is essentially a row of UIImageViews enclosed in a single subclassed UIView.

I've added a custom init method like so (node/yaml contains uiimage name data):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withNode:(NSDictionary *)node
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _node = node;
        _imageViewYAML = [node objectForKey:@"items"];
        _imageViews = [self getImageViewsForItems:_imageViewYAML];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And my getImageViewsforItems is like so (adds them all to subview):

```
-(NSArray *)getImageViewsForItems:(NSArray *)items
{
    NSMutableArray *ivs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[items count]];
    for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *item = [items objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *type = [item objectForKey:@"type"];
        NSString *name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
        UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        iv.image = image;
        iv.tag = i;
        [ivs addObject:iv];
        [self addSubview:iv];
    }
    return ivs;
}
```

Now when I add this custom view to my main view like this nothing happens:

```
CSImageViews *imageViews = [[CSImageViews alloc] initWithFrame:frame withNode:node];
[view addSubview:imageViews];
```

But if I add this 'csimageviews' container into a new uiview first it appears:

```
CSImageViews *imageViews = [[CSImageViews alloc] initWithFrame:frame withNode:node];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[v addSubview:imageViews];
[view addSubview:v];
```

thoughts?

Comment: For that nothing happens, you add v not the imageViews as subview to view. Are you sure about this?

Comment: Oops typo in stack overflow post (not my code). the nothing happens is actually adding imageViews like you would expect. I should clarify as well, it seems like the imageViews does get added (setting background color of that view turns it a different color) but the UIImageViews within CSImageViews do not appear.

Comment: try assigning some frame to view iv....I don't know if i am getting it right or not but a view should have a frame to make it clear where to display it in its parent....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid error by me. In this particular subclassed UIView I have a method that was called every time its parent view controller was shown. This method actually removed all subviews from the view... so I wasn't able to see the uiimageviews when I rendered it in the initial view... doh.